# App Script: What's the shorter way to get the range of multiple cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the data from the Source sheet to my Target sheet. Is there a version where I can shorten this code? It seems to be that the .getRange can only accept one string.

When I try this line of code `const sRange = sSheetDay.getRange('I4', '15', 'I6');` and so on, it always says it can't find the range. I know my questioning is not that good, especially I'm really a beginner at this. Hopefully someone has the same experience.

My main goal to this is to copy the data from a specific cell. And I can't seem to find the solution.

```
  function copyDataFilters() {
  const dTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sSheetDay = dTable.getSheetByName('Day 1');

  const sRange = sSheetDay.getRange('I4');
  const sRange2 = sSheetDay.getRange('I5');
  const sRange3 = sSheetDay.getRange('I6');
  const sRange4 = sSheetDay.getRange('I7');
  const sRange5 = sSheetDay.getRange('I8');
  const sRange6 = sSheetDay.getRange('I9');
  const sRange7 = sSheetDay.getRange('I12');
  const sRange8 = sSheetDay.getRange('I13');
  const sRange9 = sSheetDay.getRange('I16');
  const sRange10 = sSheetDay.getRange('I17');
  const sRange11 = sSheetDay.getRange('I20');
  const sRange12 = sSheetDay.getRange('I21');
  const sRange13 = sSheetDay.getRange('I24');
  const sRange14 = sSheetDay.getRange('I25');
  const sRange15 = sSheetDay.getRange('I27');

  const sValue = sRange.getValues();
  const sValue2 = sRange2.getValues();
  const sValue3 = sRange3.getValues();
  const sValue4 = sRange4.getValues();
  const sValue5 = sRange5.getValues();
  const sValue6 = sRange6.getValues();
  const sValue7 = sRange7.getValues();
  const sValue8 = sRange8.getValues();
  const sValue9 = sRange9.getValues();
  const sValue10 = sRange10.getValues();
  const sValue11 = sRange11.getValues();
  const sValue12 = sRange12.getValues();
  const sValue13 = sRange13.getValues();
  const sValue14 = sRange14.getValues();
  const sValue15 = sRange15.getValues();
  

  const targetSheet = dTable.getSheetByName('All filters report');
  const targetRange = targetSheet.getRange('B4:C4');
  const targetRange2 = targetSheet.getRange('B5:C5');
  const targetRange3 = targetSheet.getRange('B6:C6');
  const targetRange4 = targetSheet.getRange('B7:C7');
  const targetRange5 = targetSheet.getRange('B8:C8');
  const targetRange6 = targetSheet.getRange('B9:C9');
  const targetRange7 = targetSheet.getRange('B11:C11');
  const targetRange8 = targetSheet.getRange('B12:C12');
  const targetRange9 = targetSheet.getRange('B14:C14');
  const targetRange10 = targetSheet.getRange('B15:C15');
  const targetRange11 = targetSheet.getRange('B17:C17');
  const targetRange12 = targetSheet.getRange('B18:C18');
  const targetRange13 = targetSheet.getRange('B20:C20');
  const targetRange14 = targetSheet.getRange('B21:C21');
  const targetRange315 = targetSheet.getRange('B24:C24');

  targetRange.setValue(sValue);
  targetRange2.setValue(sValue2);
  targetRange3.setValue(sValue3);
  targetRange4.setValue(sValue4);
  targetRange5.setValue(sValue5);
  targetRange6.setValue(sValue6);
  targetRange7.setValue(sValue7);
  targetRange8.setValue(sValue8);
  targetRange9.setValue(sValue9);
  targetRange10.setValue(sValue10);
  targetRange11.setValue(sValue11);
  targetRange12.setValue(sValue12);
  targetRange13.setValue(sValue13);
  targetRange14.setValue(sValue14);
  targetRange315.setValue(sValue15);
}
```

Comment: please don't tag languages that aren't relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

Use getRangeList
From the references

```
// Get a list of ranges A1:D4, F1:H4.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var rangeList  = sheet.getRangeList(['A1:D4', 'F1:H4']);
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangelista1notations
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#getrangelista1notations

Answer (score 0):

```
function elfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  //you can do this with values
  const [v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,,,v12,v13,,,v16,v17,v18,v19,v20,v21,,,v24,v25,v26,v27] = sh.getRange("I4:I27").getValues();
  Logger.log(v4);
  //unfortunatey you cannot do this with ranges.  It resullts in an error
  const [I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9,,,I12,I13,,,I16,I17,I18,I19,I20,I21,,,I24,I25,I26,I27] = sh.getRange("I4:I27");
  Logger.log(I4.getValue());
}
```

So were stuck with handling multiple ranges with a rangelist as shown Ruben's answer

Answer (score 0):

In the current stage, when the different values are trying to be got from and put to the scattered cells, the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) has no methods for directly achieving this goal. So, in order to directly achieve this goal, as the current workaround, Sheets API can be used. When this is reflected in a sample script by including the goal of your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function copyDataFilters2() {
  const srcSheet = "Day 1";
  const dstSheet = "All filters report";
  const src = ["I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9", "I12", "I13", "I16", "I17", "I20", "I21", "I24", "I25", "I27"].map(e => `'${srcSheet}'!${e}`);
  const dst = ["B4:C4", "B5:C5", "B6:C6", "B7:C7", "B8:C8", "B9:C9", "B11:C11", "B12:C12", "B14:C14", "B15:C15", "B17:C17", "B18:C18", "B20:C20", "B21:C21", "B24:C24"].map(e => `'${dstSheet}'!${e}`);
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ssId, { ranges: src }).valueRanges.map(({ values }) => values ? [Array(2).fill(values[0][0])] : [[""]]);
  const data = values.map((e, i) => ({ values: e, range: dst[i] }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the cells `"I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9", "I12", "I13", "I16", "I17", "I20", "I21", "I24", "I25", "I27"` of "Day 1" sheet, and the retrieved values are put to the cells of `"B4:C4", "B5:C5", "B6:C6", "B7:C7", "B8:C8", "B9:C9", "B11:C11", "B12:C12", "B14:C14", "B15:C15", "B17:C17", "B18:C18", "B20:C20", "B21:C21", "B24:C24"`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)